# From Command to Android

Tags: java, android, java-me

I'm used to working in J2ME. I wanted to do something on Android, but I just can't get how to replace the command class in the events Android scenario.

Comment: Please add some more details regarding what exactly you are trying to accomplish, for those of us unfamiliar with your particular J2ME setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to add commands and want them appear in a built-in menu? When user selects one of them you want a predefined function to be called? If I understand your question right and your problem is the same as above here is the solution:

Android provides a built-in menu and let you create your own menu options. Just like in J2ME as you create some menu options(commands in J2ME) they appear in menu automatically.(The menu that appears when the user hits the menu key on the handset)

To add menu to your Activity override `onCreateOptionsMenu`

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.add(0, MENU_ITEM_ID, 0, "First Menu Option");
        return true;
    }
```

Then when user selects an item in the menu `onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item)` callback is invoked. So you can catch your menu option as follows:

```
@Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case MENU_ITEM_ID:
                yourFunction(); //your function for this particular item
                return true;
        }

        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }
```

If there were more items(options) in menu, you would catch them in switch by their ids.

hope that helps

Comment: @Peter Canthropus You are welcome. Can you mark the answer as accepted so that this question ıs lısted as solved. Cheers